# Correspondence between dual of the space of continuous maps and signed measures

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

On the first page of Chapter 4 of Einsiedler an Ward's *Ergodic Theory: With a View Towards Number Theory*, the following statement is found:

Let $(X, d)$ be a compact metric.
Recall that the dual space $C(X)^*$ of continuous real functionals on $C(X)$ of continuous functions $X\to \mathbf R$ can be naturally identified with the space of finite signed measures on $X$ equipped with the weak* topology.

I want to confirm if the correspondence is given by the following map:

Let $\mathcal F$ be the space of all the finite signed measures on $X$.
Define $\phi:\mathcal F\to C(X)^*$ as
$$\phi(\mu) = (f\mapsto \int f\ d\mu)$$

Comment: That is correct. This is, in fact, an isometric isomorphism if you endow measures with total variation norm.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you confirm one more thing? Is the weak* topology on $\mathcal F$ (see OP) defined as follows: We say $\mu_n\to \mu$ in the weak* topology if $\int_X f\ d\mu_n\to \int_X f\ d\mu$ for all $f\in C(X)$?

Comment: Yes. Probabilists wrongly call this weak convergence, but it is weak* convergence.